# how to set invisible RTL mark in input text field

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `<input type="text">` in an RTL page in which the user enter numbers separated with "/" ex: `2014/555/144`

The user enters `144` then `/` then `555` then `/` then `2014` and I add RTL byte marks in order to change the orientation between the various components.
The code below works well but when I moved to Bootstrap, the RTL byte marks became visible instead of being applied.

```
<input id="inputId" type="text" onkeypress="return replace('inputId',event,'/','/&rlm;');" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    function replace(id, evt, a, b) {
        var keyCode = evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        expr = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
        if (expr == a) {
            var st = document.getElementById(id).value;
            var st2 = st.substring(0, st.length);
            document.getElementById(id).value = st2 + b;
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I guess it is visible due to the font, perhaps change the font explicitly.

Comment: I ve changed the font (to traditionnel arabic) but the problem persist

Comment: Can you set up a live page that shows the issue? Either using JSFiddle or in any other way.

Comment: Also, what version of Bootstrap are you using? 3?

Comment: thks ! I ve found a solution ;

Comment: Great! Then add and accept your own answer so everyone could benefit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thks ! I ve found a solution ; 
when I was making transformation to my code to send it to you (my project is in .net  mvc 3..) the input works as I want : the problem was in the call of replace function before the transformation to html
-the code that doesnt work :

```
@Html.TextBox("inputId", "", new { onkeypress="return replace('inputId',event,'/','/&rlm;');", placeholder = "Number", @class = "input-small",dir="rtl" })
```

-the code that works :

```
<div onkeypress="return replace('inputId',event,'/','/&rlm;');" >
    @Html.TextBox("inputId", "", new { placeholder = "Number", @class = "input-small",dir="rtl" })
</div>
```

and bootstrap was innocent !